# Remove extra blank lines in VBA

Tags: vba, userform

I there anyway to alter the below code for TextBox1 so it only removes blank lines and not blank spaces? 

**From:** 
Line 1 
      
      
      
      Line 2

---

**To:**
 Line 1
    
    Line 2

```
 trim(TextBox1.Value & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Dim xArr() as string
xArr = Split(TextBox1.Value, vbCrLf)
TextBox1.Value = ""

for i = 0 to Ubound(xArr)
    If Trim(xArr(i)) <> "" Then
        TextBox1.value = TextBox1.value & xArr(i) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next
```